# Attribute error: can't set attribute for pygame Sprite inheritance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, pygame

I have a working code with an HPBar class --> inherits from ProgressBar class --> inherits from pygame.sprite.Sprite. I decided to create a Widget class to have the following inheritance flow: HPBar --> ProgressBar --> Widget --> pygame.sprite.Sprite. The point in doing so is for flexibility especially when adding more widgets like buttons, textboxes, etc. However, in my revision I encountered `Attribute error: can't set attribute`. Details are as follows.

Somewhere in my code I have this `HPBar` instantiation:

```
hp_bar = HPBar(
    x=x, y=y,
    entity=self.player,
    groups=[self.camera, self.extras],
)
```

**Working Code:**
*This worked prior to the revision.*

```
class HPBar(ProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, entity, *args, **kwargs):
        max_value = entity.stats["max_hp"]
        value = entity.stats["hp"]
        super().__init__(
            max_value=max_value, value=value,
            width=32, height=5,
            *args, **kwargs
        )

class ProgressBar(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(
            self,
            x: float,
            y: float,
            width: int,
            height: int,
            groups: List[pygame.sprite.AbstractGroup] = [],
            max_value: int,
            value: int,
            *args, **kwargs
    ):
        super().__init__(groups)

    @property
    def image(self):
        _image = # pygame surface
        return _image
```

**Revised Code:**
*The code with the Attribute error.*

```
class ProgressBar(Widget):
    def __init__(
            self,
            max_value: int,
            value: int,
            *args, **kwargs
    ):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def image(self):
        _image = # pygame surface
        return _image

class Widget(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(
            self,
            x: float, y: float,
            width: int, height: int,
            groups: List[pygame.sprite.AbstractGroup] = [],
    ):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
```

**Traceback Error:**

```
File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Working\Personal\platformer1\game_models\windows\platformer_window.py", line 127, in load_level
    hp_bar = HPBar(
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Working\Personal\platformer1\game_models\sprites\hp_bar.py", line 16, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Working\Personal\platformer1\contrib\models\widgets\progress_bars\progress_bar.py", line 24, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Working\Personal\platformer1\contrib\models\widgets\widget.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

**Few debugging attempts:**

I tried to print out the `width` and `height` arguments inside the `Widget` class to make sure I'm receiving and sending the correct data type:

In Widget class:

```
        super().__init__(groups)
        print(width, height)
        print(type(width), type(height))
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
```

Print result:

```
32 5
<class 'int'> <class 'int'>
```

Moreover, I have had this implementation resembling my Widget class implementation and this works fine:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((16, 32))
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ok, noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. You can't have a method/[property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) and an attribute with the same name. `image` can be either an attribute or a property. But you can't have 2 objects with the same name.

The following is not possible:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 1

    def bar(self):
        return 2

print(Foo().bar())
```

> ```
>    print(Foo().bar())
> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
> ```

Also not possible:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 1

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return 2

print(Foo().bar)
```

> ```
>    self.bar = 1
> AttributeError: can't set attribute 'bar'
> ```

---

However you can define a [setter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar = 1
        self.bar = 2

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self._bar

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, value):
        self._bar = value

print(Foo().bar)
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

Comment: That makes sense. I always thought @property would make methods act like attributes thus can override parent attributes. My bad.

Comment: @JoboFernandez You can define a [setter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). See the answer

Comment: Thanks for the idea. My code is working so far, and I'm using image method with property decorator in my Widget class. I'll keep your suggestion in mind for future cases.